# Test are being run twice and aren't closing down

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I have a java automation script being run on Selenium, for some reason the script seems to initialised twice.  The first script passes but doesn't close down, this causes a second run of the same script which also passes but does close down.

This happens on all the scripts that I run and thus causes loads of window to open and not close(very messy)

I have created a teardown method which can be seen below.  This is part of my Selenium set up class

```
package support;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class SeleniumSetup {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public SeleniumSetup(WebDriver driver)
    {

    }

    public SeleniumSetup() {

    }

    public void prepareBrowserForSelenium() {

//      setup();
        if(DriverSingleton.getDriver() == null)
        {
            setup();    
        }
        else
        {
            driver = DriverSingleton.getDriver();
        }

    }

    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Selenium and drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }


    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Here's my code for the BasePage

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

Here's the class I use for running my scripts:

```
package support;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
//      features = "src/test/java/features/ABTestingPage.feature"
//      features = "src/test/java/features/Checkboxes.feature"
//      features = "src/test/java/features/Dropdown.feature"
//      features = "src/test/java/features/AutomationLandingPage.feature"
        features = "src/test/java/features/ChallengingDOM.feature"

//      features = "src/test/java/@ABTestingPage"


        ,glue={"steps"}
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Here are my Steps which includes my SeleniumSetup class

```
package steps;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import pages.ChallengingDOMPage;
import pages.DropdownPage;
import support.SeleniumSetup;

public class ChallengingDOMSteps extends SeleniumSetup{

    public ChallengingDOMSteps()throws Exception{
        prepareBrowserForSelenium();    
    }

    @Given("^I am on the landing page$")
    public void i_am_on_the_landing_page() throws Throwable {
        new ChallengingDOMPage(driver).landingPage();
    }

    @When("^I select \"(.*?)\"$")
    public void i_select(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        new ChallengingDOMPage(driver).selectChallengingDOM();  
    }

    @Then("^I will be navigated to the \"(.*?)\" page$")
    public void i_will_be_navigated_to_the_page(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        if(arg1.equalsIgnoreCase("Challenging DOM"))
        new  ChallengingDOMPage(driver).verifyChallegingDOMPage();

        else if(arg1.equals("Dropdown"))
         new DropdownPage(driver).verifyDropdownHeading();
     }
}
```

I think my code for the step is ok.

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class ChallengingDOMPage extends BasePage {

    public ChallengingDOMPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

        By landingPageCopy = By.className("heading");


    public void landingPage() {

        driver.findElement(landingPageCopy).getText();

        System.out.println("verified copy on landing page on DOM test");

    }

    public void selectChallengingDOM() {

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Challenging DOM")).click();

        System.out.println("DOM URL clicked");

    }

    public void verifyChallegingDOMPage() {

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'The hardest part')]")).isDisplayed());
        System.out.println("Copy Verified on the DOM page");

    }

}
```

This is the console output

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter (file:/C:/Users/awalker/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.3/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Starting ChromeDriver 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90) on port 43775
Only local connections are allowed.
verified copy on landing page on DOM test
DOM URL clicked
Copy Verified on the DOM page
Starting ChromeDriver 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90) on port 34425
Only local connections are allowed.

1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m)
4 Steps ([32m4 passed[0m)
0m11.433s
```

I should land on this page http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/,  navigate to http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/challenging_dom and verify the copy

Comment: Please put the code for your BasePage as well, would be helpful to get the actual issue

Comment: Thanks but may you please put it in the question, would be easier to understand the code there :)

Comment: @SameerArora   here you go.   

    package pages;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    public class BasePage {
 
     protected WebDriver driver;
 
     public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
      this.driver = driver;
     }

    }


Sorry I am a bit new to Stack so having trouble formatting my code properly

Comment: done, thanks for being patient

Comment: Are you correctly using JUnit's After, AfterClass and BeforeClass annotations? They are present int the list of imports, but it don't see them on any method.

Comment: @bangnab I've just added 'public void tearDown()' to my ChallengingDOMPage.java page.  This didn't resolve the issue

My feeling is that there is something wrong with my teardown method but can't seem to see what it is.

Comment: @awalker23 The question is how do you use the SeleniumSetup class in your tests

Comment: @bangnab I've added where I add the SeleniumSetup class to my step def above.

Comment: @awalker23 just adding a method definition for tearDown() doesn't mean that it will be run. How do you actually run your tests?

Comment: @bangnab I use TestRunner.org I've added to code above.  Sorry if my answers are a bit painful, I am (obviously) new to automation so sometimes I am just grasping at straws

Answer (score 0):

chromedriver unlike other drivers need to be closed this way:

```
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

instead of just

```
driver.close();
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue, I am starting to think that the 'close' is a red herring and the issue is that the script is running multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how your feature file looks like. In your output it looks like you run 4 steps, but you showed us only 3 steps definitions. I've tried your setup as you described and used a simple feature file with only one scenario running all three steps in the same order as they are defined and it runs without problems with output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90) 
on port 43775
Only local connections are allowed.
verified copy on landing page on DOM test
DOM URL clicked
Copy Verified on the DOM page
```

This is the same as your output, but yous shows an additional ChromeDriver instantiation **after** that.
Look at which steps are actually run: you must have an additional step that runs after the other three and starts another webdriver.

Note also that your `tearDown()` method is never run. You need to tell cucumber to run it after the scenario is completed. You can do that by adding

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown();
}
```

in your `ChallengingDOMSteps`, note that it should be `import cucumber.api.java.After;` and not `import org.junit.After;` so that Cucumber picks it up.

Comment: You were correct I had an additional close step in the feature file, So I assume that this was causing the duplication.  I remeoved it and when a test passes  there are no duplicates.  However I still have two errros 1) the webpage doesn't close down. I have added public void tearDown() {
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
 }  to the selniumSet up but this hasn't had the desired effect. 2) When the page errors I am still seeing duplications of the same page.  Would that be expected? Happy to open up another question if it makes it easier.

Comment: @awalker23 look at the addition in my answer. This should solve your issue.